# Postgres Duration Storage

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I would like to store a duration in database, in my case it's a training duration (sport). We set when we do the training (datetime) and how long the session is (duration).

At the moment, I've choose the `Time` type, then I've: 01:00:00 for an hour of training, and retrieve a Datetime object in PHP (but I think it's not ideal to sum them for exemple) and in my form I've an undesired behavior: the html time type automatically set the current hour when the time is empty.

I hesitate in:

- keep time, it seem logical/simple to have something like: 00:00:00
- store it as secondes or minutes as an integer, maybe simpler to do sum of training amount for exemple (need to create a converter to display it as 00:00 or 00:00:00, and find a nice way to fill it in form)
- a way I've not think ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sounds like an INTERVAL, a standard datatype in PostgreSQL. Presentation is something that should be done imho in the GUI, not in the database. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct data type to store a duration is `interval`.

This makes it easy to do date arithmetic: you can simply add the duration to the start time to get the end time:

```
SELECT INTERVAL '01:30:00';

 interval 
----------
 01:30:00
(1 row)

SELECT TIME '09:00:00' + INTERVAL '01:30:00';

 ?column? 
----------
 10:30:00
(1 row)

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2021-03-28 02:00:00+01' + INTERVAL '01:30:00';

        ?column?        
------------------------
 2021-03-28 04:30:00+02
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn’t know that type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is.  Postgres has no problem using `sum()` on the `time` data type:

```
select sum(t)
from (values ('03:12:00'::time), ('05:27:00'), ('18:59')) v(t)
```

You can also use `interval`.

You might have issues if individual durations exceed 24 hours.  If that is a potential issue, just use hours, minutes, or seconds.

If you have a problem with "empty" values, then you will need to set them explicitly.  It sounds like a bug on the HTML side.

Comment: Why `time` and not `interval`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . . . Duh.  That makes sense too.  In fact more sense -- except that values in excess of 24 hours start to include days as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the time sum. Because I didn’t know the Interval type, I’ve not think to use it. But it appear to be the best way to do. Thanks again for your help too.